# No muestra las coincidencias de dos consultas distintas

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando en unas consultas de mysql en Kubuntu y tengo el siguiente enunciado

"- obtener todos los datos de los empleados que nacieron en 1968 o 1969 y que tienen el mismo numero de hijos que algun empleado del departamento 111."

Con esta consulta obtengo todos los nacidos en esas fechas

```
``mysql> select * from temple where (fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31');``
```

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Y con esta consulta obtengo todos los posibles valores que toma el numero de hijos en el departamento 111

```
`select distinct numhi from temple where numde = 111;`
```

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

He intentado la siguiente consulta

```
``mysql> select * from temple where (fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31') IN (select distinct numhi from temple where numde = 111);``
```

Pero me devuelve todos los empleados de toda la tabla que tengo.

Me tendria que salir en la consulta que quiero las 3 primeras filas de la primera consulta que cumplen la condicion de nacidos en el 1968 al 1969 y que tienen 0,1,2 o 3 hijos

Comment: No entiendo que tratas de hacer.. pero esto: (fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31') IN (select distinct numhi from temple where numde = 111); esta mal.. el IN, es contra alguna collumna de tu select... vos estas usando el in contra algo que da true... igual, para poder ayudarte mas, necesitamos ver las tablas, datos de ejemplo y el resultado esperado..

Comment: Ya añadi los datos y el resultado que espero obtener

Answer (score 0):

Con un inner join se soluciona my consulta de una manera algo larga pero resolutiva

```
select t1.* 
from temple t1 
inner join (
         select distinct numhi 
         from temple 
         where numde = 111
       ) as t2 on t1.numhi=t2.numhi
where t1.fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31';
```

Comment: Si a la consulta de la otra respuesta, le cambiabas el = por IN, entonces te andaba perfecto...

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

@Black171 has provado de ponerle el segundo select en el where?

```
mysql> select * from temple where (fecna between '1968-01-01' and '1969-12-31') and numhi = (select distinct numhi from temple where numde = 111);
```

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error 
**ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Comment: Te dejo un linq sobre subconsultas haber si asi te sale @Black171 https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15 Aunque sea Sql server y tu estes usando mysql el lenguaje es el mismo casi.